# Conversations belong to multiple users, but user A deletes and user B doesn't. How we prevent this from being returned?

Tags: mysql, eloquent

I'm building a chat feature in our application. The basic chat works, we had a query to get the conversations belonging to a user, get a conversation, messages, etc.

Now, we want to add a feature where a participant of a conversation (conversations can have multiple participants) can delete a chat on their end, but this **won't delete** the conversation in the server. Instead, we will mark the conversation as deleted from X point for that user. In that case, when a participant that deleted a conversation, requests in our API for the conversation again, he won't see messages prior to his deletion.

To understand the concept clearly, it's the same way WhatsApp, Telegram or most of the chats applications work nowadays. When having user A and B are interacting, if user B chooses to delete the conversation from his phone, user A will still see the whole conversation. If user B (or A), texts again in the conversation, user B will only see the new texts.

I'm not entirely sure how this works on their ends, but the structure that seems to work for us is the following one:

```
CREATE TABLE `conversations` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `starter_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `last_message_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `conversations_starter_id_index` (`starter_id`),
  KEY `conversations_last_message_id_index` (`last_message_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `conversation_participants` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `conversation_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `participant_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `deleted_from_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `conversation_participants_conversation_id_index` (`conversation_id`),
  KEY `conversation_participants_participant_id_index` (`participant_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `conversation_messages` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `conversation_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sender_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `conversation_messages_conversation_id_index` (`conversation_id`),
  KEY `conversation_messages_sender_id_index` (`sender_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

As you see in `conversation_participants` we've added a `deleted_from_id`. This `deleted_from_id` will get updated when user B sends a request to the server to delete the conversation. It will send the conversation_id and the latest conversation_message_id he has seen and update accordingly.

We use Laravel as our framework and Eloquent to easily generate queries with relationships. We have an endpoint that requests the latest 25 conversations for a user, and then we paginate them. This is the query being generated for this type of query:

```
select
  `conversations`.*,
  `conversation_participants`.`participant_id` as `pivot_participant_id`,
  `conversation_participants`.`conversation_id` as `pivot_conversation_id`,
  `conversation_participants`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`,
  `conversation_participants`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at`
from
  `conversations`
  inner join `conversation_participants` on `conversations`.`id` = `conversation_participants`.`conversation_id`
where
  `conversation_participants`.`participant_id` = 1
  and exists (
    select
      *
    from
      `conversation_messages`
    where
      `conversations`.`id` = `conversation_messages`.`conversation_id`
  )
order by
  `id` desc
```

The query above is pretty simple, it returns the conversations for a specific user. Using Laravel's `Conversation::with('messages')...`, it allows us to easily filter conversations that have messages (we don't want empty conversations being returned).

The problem is that we tried to filter more and prevent conversations that the user has deleted on his phone to be shown in that query. We haven't found a way.

Our first guess was to simply add tweak the `exists()` limiting the `conversation_messages.id`, like:

```
select
  `conversations`.*,
  `conversation_participants`.`participant_id` as `pivot_participant_id`,
  `conversation_participants`.`conversation_id` as `pivot_conversation_id`,
  `conversation_participants`.`deleted_from_id` as `pivot_deleted_from_id`,
  `conversation_participants`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`,
  `conversation_participants`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at`
from
  `conversations`
  inner join `conversation_participants` on `conversations`.`id` = `conversation_participants`.`conversation_id`
where
  `conversation_participants`.`participant_id` = 1
  and exists (
    select
      *
    from
      `conversation_messages`
    where
      `conversations`.`id` = `conversation_messages`.`conversation_id`
      and `id` > conversation_participants.deleted_from_id
  )
order by
  `id` desc
```

This will "work", but if the user has deleted a message and, let's say, there are conversations with messages older than the `and`id`> conversation_participants.deleted_from_id`, no other conversations will be returned. That's wrong, as it prevents any other conversation to shown even when they have messages and belong to the participant.

We also tried a different approach, using some joins in the `exists()` to try to prevent having the "deleted conversation" to show on the list:

```
select
  `conversations`.*,
  `conversation_participants`.`participant_id` as `pivot_participant_id`,
  `conversation_participants`.`conversation_id` as `pivot_conversation_id`,
  `conversation_participants`.`deleted_from_id` as `pivot_deleted_from_id`,
  `conversation_participants`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`,
  `conversation_participants`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at`
from
  `conversations`
  inner join `conversation_participants` on `conversations`.`id` = `conversation_participants`.`conversation_id`
where
  `conversation_participants`.`participant_id` = 1
  and exists (
    select
      `conversation_messages`.*
    from
      `conversation_messages`
    join
      `conversations` on `conversations`.`id` = `conversation_messages`.`conversation_id`
    join
      `conversation_participants` on `conversations`.`id` = `conversation_participants`.`conversation_id`
    where
      `conversations`.`id` = `conversation_messages`.`conversation_id`
      and `conversation_participants`.`participant_id` = 1
      and `conversation_messages`.`id` > `conversation_participants`.`deleted_from_id`
  )
order by
  `id` desc
```

But unfortunately, that didn't work either.

To make testing more convenient, I've set up a DB Fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q6S3GfZNCbvYbtvRwXJxN7/0

This fiddle has multiple users, multiple conversations and multiple messages. As you see, if you run the query right away it will return 28 conversations that belong to the given participant.

That said if you notice in the table conversation_participants, there is a row for participant_id=1 that on conversation_id=82 the delete message is the 82: `(55,28,1,82,'2020-01-31 10:01:08','2020-01-31 10:01:08'),` (line 166 in the fiddle). The message 82 is the last message in the conversation_id=28, therefore, it should **not show up** in the query as it has no messages.

In our effort to find a solution, we also thought that maybe having the row `conversations.last_message_id` would be helpful to prevent conversations to show up... but we aren't sure about this either as we couldn't find a solution. I've decided to leave it in the SQL in case it's useful to find a solution.

How can I get the desired results? What I'm missing out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a bit long winded, but you got there in the end

Comment: @Strawberry hahaha, I really didn't know how to ask properly

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with a much simpler sample data set, featuring the minimal number of columns, rows and data pertinent to the problem; I just don't feel like wading through all this `$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG` and `Lorem ipsit` stuff, and somehow, I doubt it's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do.

Conversation contains Messages
Messages contain the participants.

I would not keep "Conversation_Participants" as seen in your case. 
Instead, I would keep "Message_Participants".

This would be my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `conversations` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `starter_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `last_message_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `conversations_starter_id_index` (`starter_id`),
  KEY `conversations_last_message_id_index` (`last_message_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `conversation_messages` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `conversation_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sender_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `conversation_messages_conversation_id_index` (`conversation_id`),
  KEY `conversation_messages_sender_id_index` (`sender_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `message_participants` (
      `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `message_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `participant_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      )
```

I have omitted foreign key creations, you can add as required.

Now, whenever a message arrives in a conversation which has "n" participants, "n" number of entries would be made in message_participants table.

So, when a participant deletes a message or group of messages from his chat, you can delete corresponding entries in the table "message_participants" pertaining to that message and participant.

This way, a participant can delete any message from any chat in any order. In your logic you have mentioned "last_message_id". This will limit the user to not access messages beyond a particular id, but with my logic, he can keep few messages from 2014 and then delete everything after that until 2018, then keep 2 months chat from 2018 and delete the rest. 
I hope you got the point and hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm... that's a really interesting approach. The idea behind the participants was that we will primarily have 1-to-1 chats, but the idea is to allow up to a few participants per conversation. I clearly see on my example how to find the conversations a user belongs to... but, how would you find the conversations "I can see" (if that's the right word) with your table structure? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see your approach quite useful, as it will allow us to have things like delivered_at or seen_at by each participant... Also, participants who join a conversation late, wouldn't see the whole thing which I also think works in our UX.